# Buildroot build fails with the error "ERROR: we shouldn't have a /etc/ld.so.conf file"

Tags: arm, embedded-linux, buildroot

I am using Buildroot version 2022.11 to compile a custom Linux image for a TI Sitara 437x (ARM A9). I am using an external toolchain, which took a while to configure properly, but I think everything has been set properly by now.

The build goes well, until the very end, where I get the following error:

`find /home/sc3/buildroot/output/target   \( -name 'ld-*.so*' -o -name 'libpthread*.so*' \) -print0 | xargs -0 -r /home/sc3/buildroot/output/host/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabihf-strip --remove-section=.comment --remove-section=.note --strip-debug 2>/dev/null || true test -f /home/sc3/buildroot/output/target/etc/ld.so.conf && \ { echo "ERROR: we shouldn't have a /etc/ld.so.conf file"; exit 1; } || true ERROR: we shouldn't have a /etc/ld.so.conf file Makefile:721: recipe for target 'target-finalize' failed make[1]: *** [target-finalize] Error 1 Makefile:84: recipe for target '_all' failed make: *** [_all] Error 2`

This error comes from the Makefile.

If I delete the file "/etc/ld.so.conf" and restart the build, it finishes successfully.

I tried to find the reason of this error, but couldn't find anything.

Do you have any hints of what causes this error? What should be done to fix this? And why is it an issue?

Many thanks everyone!